# which is better gwt-rpc or json when considering several factors listed below

Tags: json, gwt, gxt, gwt-rpc, mgwt

queries on Gwt rpc and JSON

1. first of all,is it correct to compare both?
2. which one be the best technology for server communication?
3. which kind  of applications better to go for gwt rpc and which to go for json?
4. which one is efficient in performance?
5. if my app brings huge data from the server to client for every request 
   then which is good,rpc / json?
6. I'm developing two apps, one is by GXT(a web app) and the other one is by MGWT,  which technology is good for web app and which is good for mobile app.
   I'm a beginner,pls clarify my queries.
   thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

1) You can compare them. We have use cases for both gwt-rpc and json in our 200+ screen enterprise product ( all in GWT )
2) There is no single choice answer for this query. Each flavour of gwt server communication has its pros-cons.

3a) GWT-RPC is best suited for CRUD-Application when all the client server side data provider/consumers are to coded in java. GWT-RPC lends to easy optimisations and code-refactorings.

3b) In our use case we found JSON best suited for data consumption when your api's output need to be consumed by other clients which can be coded in PHP/JavaScript/Android/IOS.
We generate JSON data on server side and serve them up via Rest Services. We have a GWT Client which only consumes this JSON data to render charts.

4) GWT-RPC is more efficient for its use case i.e Client is always in GWT Code.

5) You should never design with HUGE data. At any given point of time a user can only see "One Screen" of data. Why then fetch lots of data?
6. GXT is by Sencha and they also have a mobile focused library apart from that. However mGWT might be a good choice as it is open source and the developer got hired to be part of GWT Team !!!

Comment: thanks @SSR , can u pls provide brief discription on point (3.b)

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider [RequestFactory](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) if your application is data-oriented. RequestFactory minimizes the amount of traffic between server and client by automatically tracking which parts of your object graph have changed

The link above it briefly discusses RF vs RPC.

Answer (score 0):

if u are useing gwt it means i want to write client code in java. i think use RPC . i used before REST , my applicaipn canfused in a time. with rpc also your client code be cleaner.

this is my experience.